# To add rolling window function in scala with multiple filters

Tags: scala

I am new to scala. I have one requirement to add rolling window function in scala. I was partially successful.

1. Currently I am trying to add more filter criteria with **or**
   conditions to be included in category   e.g `category=="BB" || "CC"`
2. And also to include the maximum transaction for a window per category per account.

Below is my snippet.

```
def analytics(ts: List[Transaction], day: Int): Map[String, (Double, Double)] = {

  val roll = ts
   .filter(trans => trans.transactionDay >= day - 30 && trans.transactionDay < day)
   .groupBy(_.accountId)
  val sum1 = roll.mapValues(_.filter(_.category == "BB"))
                      .mapValues(_.map(_.transactionAmount).sum)
  val sum2 = roll.mapValues(_.map(_.transactionAmount).sum)
  val allCounts = roll.mapValues(_.length)
 sum2.map { case (id, sum) => 
    id -> (sum1.getOrElse(id, 0.0), sum / allCounts(id)) 
}
}
```

Desired output

[image]

input

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure what you're asking, but it seems your main issues are that you need to group by day as well as account, and you need an inner map from category to sum over that category. I don't know how you're processing the output into a spreadsheet, but you'll need some way to get the full list of categories if you want to format it nicely (and I suppose the full list of categories might not be represented in your input data, so you'll need to be careful there too).

If you use the return type `Map[(Int, String), (Double, Double, Map[String, Double])]` for your function, where the `Int` is the day, and the inner `Map` is from categories to sum, then you'll have the data in the right shape. To make the method fit that signature you'll need to make a few changes:

1. `groupBy(t => (t.transactionDay, t.accountId))` so that you get your day window. This isn't a rolling window, but I'm not sure that you actually want a [rolling window](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average) anyway - let me know if I'm wrong.
2. Move the rest of the code to the inside of a single `mapValues` function. (Not strictly necessary, but neater than your current approach.)
3. Add a field (inside `mapValues`, with the max and average) created by doing another `groupBy`, but this time on categories.